# Cannot run simple java code from real BlackBerry device

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new to BlackBerry development. I downloaded Eclipse plugin for BlackBerry. I've just created a HelloWorld project. It runs well on a simulator but when I connect my BlackBerry Q10 to my PC, it doesn't work. (I am selecting in package explorer, BlackBerry -> Load projects on device, and it doesn't work, not even getting an action. When I search program in the phone, there is no application that I created) It's not needed but I also did code signing. In Android development, I was simply connecting the device and the code runs perfectly.However, in BlackBerry, it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong/missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the Q10 is blackberry os10, while eclipse/java is for blackberry 7 and lower.

From what I understand OS10 was completely reworked, which means that project won't be compatible. I think they switched to c++.

The reason it works in the simulator is its an os7 (or lower) simulator.